# Use A Variable for an Array of Keys in Multidimentional Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array, $json_data, I'm trying to parse with a for loop:

This is the array:

```
array(2) {
    ["data"]=>
    array(4) {
        ["children"]=>
        array(25) {
            [0]=>
            ["first_key"]=>
            array(50) {
                ["second_key"]=> 
                string(9) "My Title"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in PHP, I set this as $json_data and start pulling data out with a for loop

```
foreach  ( $json_data['data']['children'] as $key => $value ) {
    echo $title = $value['first_key']['second_key'];
}
```

Outputs "My Title" as expected.

My question (and if my question is poorly worded, please advise) is, can I set the keys as a variable? I know that I can't set it as a string, but can I pass array of keys to $value like:

```
$key_array = array('first_key' => array('second_key'));

foreach  ( $json_data['data']['children'] as $key => $value ) {
    echo $title = $value[$key_array];
}
```

Or something like that?

Making a function to which I could pass the $array to a function that has the $key_array set would also be great, like:

echo get_array_value( $array, $array_keys );

but would love a shove in the right direction.

Comment: Do you need to get the data out of the array?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, hence the question ;). I would like to set the "path" to the correct key/value pair before the array is created.

Comment: Is it always the same path?

Comment: No, hence my wanting to set a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, see here:

```
$key_array = array('first_key' => array('second_key'));
```

Instead of declaring a multidimensional array of keys, declare a simple array comprising of all the keys whose values you want to fetch from the original array `$json_data`, like this:

```
$array_keys = array('second_key', 'another_key');
```

And second, from your question:

> Making a function to which I could pass the `$array` to a function that has the `$key_array` set would also be great, like:
>
> ```
> echo get_array_value( $array, $array_keys );
> ```

Yes, this is certainly possible. **The solution** would be:

- Write a function `get_array_value()` and pass the original array `$json_data` and the array of keys `$array_keys` to this function.
- Create a `foreach` loop inside `get_array_value()` function that will loop through the `$array_keys` array. In each iteration of the loop, call another recursive utility function `get_array_value_utility()`.
- The `get_array_value_utility()` function will recursively loop through the array and get the required value from the array.

Here's **the code**:

```
function get_array_value_utility($array, $key){
    foreach($array as $k => $v){
        if($key == $k){
            return $v;
        }else if(is_array($v)){
            $v = get_array_value_utility($v, $key);
            if ($v != null) return $v; 
        }
    }
}

function get_array_value($array, $array_keys){
    $values = array();
    foreach($array_keys as $key){
        $values[] = get_array_value_utility($array, $key);
    }
    return $values;
}

$array_keys = array('second_key', 'another_key');
$values = get_array_value($json_data, $array_keys);

// display $values array
var_dump($values);
```

---

Here's the [**live demo**](https://eval.in/661456) (taken from @Evanrose's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066392/use-a-variable-for-an-array-of-keys-in-multidimentional-arrays-in-php/40066652?noredirect=1#comment67422266_40066652))

Comment: is this solution is flexible for any level of nesting

Comment: @EaBangalore Yes, this solution is flexible to any level of nesting.

Comment: sorry i'm not the owner(questionare)

Comment: @EaBangalore Ah, looks like I need some more coffee. ;-)

Comment: This works great except that the recursive function stops after it gets to the first key that has an array as its value but don't know why. Here's the [live demo](https://eval.in/661436). Any ideas?

Comment: changing the line return get_array_value_utility($v, $key);

Comment: Changing the line `get_array_value_utility($v, $key);` to `$v = get_array_value_utility($v, $key);` and then `if ($v != null) return $v;` fixed the issue.

Comment: @EvanRose You're indeed correct! Thanks for pointing out the bug. :-) I've updated my answer. Please *accept* the answer(if it solved your problem) to close the question.